# Maximum of function of three variables on the unit cube

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I am looking to prove that the function

$$f(x,y,z) = \frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)z(1-z)}{1 - (1-xy)z}$$

attains it's maximum at a point within the unit cube $[0,1] \times [0,1] \times [0,1]$ and NOT on the boundary.

Wolfram Alpha confirms that the max is attained not on the boundary, but actually within the cube. I have been able to show that there is a local maximum which gives this value inside the cube, but I can't see how to show that the values at the boundary don't go to infinity. For example, if we approach the vertex $(x,y,z) = (0,0,1)$ we get $0$ over $0$.

> How do I know that the function doesn't go to infinity as we tend to this vertex?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There's an extra right parenthesis in denominator--- makes it hard (to say the least) to see what $f$ is.

Comment: Could you fix the denominator, as mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: Apologies- now amended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reciprocal $1/f$ can be written as $1/[(1-x)(1-y)]$ times the sum of two terms
$$\frac{1}{xyz}+\frac{1}{1-z}.$$
As $(x,y,z) \to (0,0,1)$ (through values interior to the cube) both terms go to $+\infty$ making $f$ itself tend to $0.$

The same happens whenever both the product $xy$ and $z$ tend to zero, and these are all the points where $f$ is not defined.